# Converting circuit to block diagram

Tags: block-diagram

I need to prove that this circuit;
[image: I need to prove that this circuit;]

is equal to this block diagram.
[image: is equal to this block diagram.]

Comment: What steps have you taken to accomplish your goal?

Comment: I've solved the circuit equality and transfer function. But not further.

Comment: Show your partial solution in your question please.

Comment: It seems you can construct a transfer function and use partial fractions to separate each component in that transfer function and with that you can perhaps construct the block diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I need to prove that this circuit is equal to this block diagram*

I'd start with the block diagram and reduce it like so: -

[image]

Then solve your circuit's transfer function and compare the two formulas. Or enter the derived TF (from above) into a free simulator that can handle Laplace operators (such as Micro-cap) and compare the response with the simulated circuit.